# SapUi5 write text in many rows one under another without :

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to achive something like this in SapUi5:

```
First row
Second row
Third row
Fourth row
```

and actually all I can do is:

```
First Row:
Second row:
Third row:
Fourth row:
```

when I used:

```
<f:FormElement label="First Row"/>
<f:FormElement label="Second row"/>
<f:FormElement label="Third row"/>
<f:FormElement label="Fourth row"/>
```

Is there any chance to remove `:`? Should I use something other than label?

Comment: In what context do you need this? Is this part of a form? Or just 4 texts below eachother somewhere? Have you seen [VerticalLayout](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout)?

Comment: @TiiJ7 It is just a Panel with that rows without colon one under another. I can handle layout but the ':' is unbeatable. I used: `<f:layout>
          <f:ResponsiveGridLayout columnsM="1"/>
        </f:layout>`

Comment: It's in my Form but both `VerticalLayout` and `<f:FormElement><Text text="First row" /></f:FormElement>` work

Comment: What does the Panel actually represent? What's the role of the user? What kind of data do the rows show? Would be nice if those questions could be clarified so that we can come up with better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Option 1:*

You can use a [`sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout). As for the actual elements, a `Label` is normally more used as a caption to another element, like a form field or a table column. So for general text, you want to use `sap.m.Text`.

Sample (ignore the boilerplate of the XMLview creation):

```js
sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView"], function(XMLView) {
    XMLView.create({
        definition: $('#myView').html()
    }).then(function(oView) {
        oView.placeAt('content');
    });
});
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m,sap.ui.layout'></script>
    <script id="myView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
      <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
        
        <Panel headerText="My Panel">
          <l:VerticalLayout>
            <Text text="First row" />
            <Text text="Second row" />
            <Text text="Third row" />
            <Text text="Fourth row" />
          </l:VerticalLayout>
        </Panel>

      </mvc:View>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class='sapUiBody'><div id='content'></div></body>

</html>
```

*Option 2:*

Put the text inside a proper `Text` instead of the label, eg:

```
<f:FormElement><Text text="First row" /></f:FormElement>
```

*Option 3:*

Hide the colon with CSS, but in this case you should prefer the other options since label is not meant to just display some independent text.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS

```
.sapUiForm.sapUiFormLblColon .sapUiFormElementLbl>.sapMLabel {
   content: "" !important;
}
```

If you don't want to override the default CSS for all the form, you can give custom `class` to the `form`(like `testForm`) so that you can use the CSS to override only for the specific form.

```
.testForm.sapUiForm.sapUiFormLblColon .sapUiFormElementLbl>.sapMLabel {
   content: "" !important;
}
```